# How to take picture using inside Camera app

Tags: android, android-camera

I want to take picture using camera app built in the device with touch event even though device doesn't support that function.

What i want to realize is following.

1) When I open the native or any other camera app,

2) Take a picture with touch event instead of camera button ( This part is what i want to develop)

Below code is What I try for this.

I tried to call transparent Activity on the camera app, 
and When I get a touch event on the that Activity, 
I call Take_picture() function.

But camera.takePicture() function in the Take_picture doesn't work. ( actually it doesn't call jpegCallback function)

```
 private void Take_picture(){

    camera = Camera.open();


    if(camera != null)
    {
        camera.takePicture(null, null, jpegCallback);

    }


}


PictureCallback jpegCallback = new PictureCallback() {
    public void onPictureTaken(byte[] data, Camera camera) {
        new SaveImageTask().execute(data);


    }
};

private class SaveImageTask extends AsyncTask<byte[], Void, Void> {

    @Override
    protected Void doInBackground(byte[]... data) {
        FileOutputStream outStream = null;

        System.out.println("66666");
        // Write to SD Card
        try {
            File sdCard = Environment.getExternalStorageDirectory();
            File dir = new File (sdCard.getAbsolutePath() + "/camtest");
            dir.mkdirs();               

            String fileName = String.format("%d.jpg", System.currentTimeMillis());
            File outFile = new File(dir, fileName);

            outStream = new FileOutputStream(outFile);
            outStream.write(data[0]);
            outStream.flush();
            outStream.close();

            //Log.d(TAG, "onPictureTaken - wrote bytes: " + data.length + " to " + outFile.getAbsolutePath());

            //refreshGallery(outFile);
        } catch (FileNotFoundException e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
        } catch (IOException e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
        } finally {
        }
        return null;
    }

}
```

I couldn't get any information How to I control native camera app for take picture instantly.

Please help.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

> How to I control native camera app for take picture instantly.

You can't. You are welcome to create your own camera app that takes pictures however you want. The authors of other camera applications are welcome to implement their camera apps however they want, and they do not have to provide any means for other developers to dictate when and how the pictures are taken.

> But camera.takePicture() function in the Take_picture doesn't work

Your app should be crashing, as you should not have a valid `Camera` object. Only one app can use the camera at a time.

Comment: Then, is it possible to get instance of opened camera instead of camera.open() ??

Comment: @user2688423: No, because that is in another app's process, not yours.